# bypass a page based on condition

Tags: c#, asp.net, session

This is my load session and save session value functions. How do I retain the selected value and use it to "skip" a certain page if selected? Thank you!

```
 protected override void LoadSessionValues()
    {
       if (Session["ddlClassification"] != null)
        {
            ddlClassification.SelectedValue = (String)Session["ddlClassification"];
        }
    }

  protected override void SaveSessionValues()
    {
        Session["ddlClassification"] = ddlClassification.SelectedValue;
    }
```

Comment: if all these pages are part of ur domain  and if u have right to change the source. add check conditions to every page. and use query string to pass values

Answer (score 5):

```
if (Session["ddlClassification"].ToString() == "valueToCheckFor")
{
Response.Redirect("page1.aspx", false);
}
else
{
Response.Redirect("page2.aspx", false);
}
```

**Updated from comments below**

In page1.aspx

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Session["ddlClassification"].ToString() == "valueToCheckFor" || Session["ddlClassification"] == null)
    {
    Response.Redirect("someOtherPage.aspx", false);
    }
}
```

Comment: do i put this page to be skipped?

Comment: That depends on the flow of your pages. If you are going from page1 to page2 to page 3 and want to conditionally skip page2, it would go in the eventhandler in page1.

Comment: `@Chris Bint` what if user types `whatever.com/page1.aspx` in adress bar and hits enter? (let's assume that `Session["ddlClassification"]` gets initialized on `whatever.com/default.aspx` and has a value that indicates that page1.aspx has to be skipped) how ur code prevents user from navigating to the forbidden URL.

Comment: Add a check to page_load of the page you want to 'skip' that redirects to a page they do have access to. However, if they go direct to page1 without accessing default.aspx, there will be no value at all and you will need to check for that as well.

Comment: that means he has to be the owner or at least have the right to change source of page1, page2, etc...

Comment: My guess is that he has, as he posted sourcecode above. If not, the question is incorrectly tagged.

Comment: i have created a 5 page webform and the first page is were i get the classification value but i won't to skip the 4th page. it is not working for me at all.

Comment: As far as I can tell, you have all the information you need to make a solution for your problem. The code above will check (in the restricted page) for the value of 'ddlClassification' and the existance of the value. If the value is not correct, or the value is null, then redirect to whatever page you need to.